# Is there a PHP like short version of the ternary operator in Java?

Tags: java, php, ternary-operator

In PHP the ternary operator has a short version.

```
expr1 ? expr2 : expr3;
```

changes into

```
expr1 ? : expr3;
```

The short version returns the result of expr1 on true and expr3 on false.
This allows cool code that can populate variables based on their own current state. For example:

```
$employee = $employee ? : new Employee();
```

If `$employee == null` or evaluates to false for any other reason, the code above will create a `new Employee();` Otherwise the value in `$employee` will be reassigned to itself.

I was looking for something similar in Java, but I could not find any similar use case of the ternary operator. So I am asking if is there such a functionality or something similar that can avoid one of the expressions of the ternary operator in order to reduce duplication.

Comment: No, there isn't any short version like this in Java.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No, there is not. (A ternary operation requires, [by definition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation), three operands)

> Since PHP 5.3, it is possible to leave out the middle part of the
>   ternary operator. Expression expr1 ?: expr3 returns expr1 if expr1
>   evaluates to TRUE, and expr3 otherwise.

Source: [The PHP Manual](http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.if.php)

Just like the one in Java but in Java you need to specify both outcomes:

> The ternary
>   if-else operator works with three operands producing a value depending
>   on the truth or falsehood of a boolean assertion. It's form is as
>   follows:-

```
boolean-exp ? value1 : value2
```

Sources:

[Java specs on the ternary conditional operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.25)

[Official Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html)

[The Java.net Blogs](https://weblogs.java.net/blog/hellofadude/archive/2013/11/11/basics-java-)

Also keep in mind that, unlike Java and every other popular language with a similar operator, `?:` is left associative in PHP. So this:

```
<?php
$arg = "T";
$vehicle = ( ( $arg == 'B' ) ? 'bus' : 
             ( $arg == 'A' ) ? 'airplane' : 
         ( $arg == 'T' ) ? 'train' : 
         ( $arg == 'C' ) ? 'car' : 
         ( $arg == 'H' ) ? 'horse' : 
                               'feet' );
echo $vehicle;
```

prints `horse` instead of `train` (which is what you would expect in Java)

Sources:

http://eev.ee/blog/2012/04/09/php-a-fractal-of-bad-design/#operators