# Is there a shorthand for the ternary operator in C#?

Tags: c#, ternary-operator

## Background

In PHP there is a shorthand for the ternary operator:

```
$value = "";
echo $value ?: "value was empty"; // same as $value == "" ? "value was empty" : $value;
```

In JS there's also an equivalent:

```
var value = "";
var ret = value || "value was empty"; // same as var ret = value == "" ? "value was empty" : value;
```

But in C#, there's (as far as i know) only the "full" version works:

```
string Value = "";
string Result = Value == string.Empty ? "value was empty" : Value;
```

**So my question is: Is there a shorthand for the ternary operator in C#, and if not, is there a workaround?**

## Research

I found the following questions, but they're referring to use the ternary operator as shorthand to if-else:

[shorthand If Statements: C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6073563/shorthand-if-statements-c-sharp)

[Benefits of using the conditional ?: (ternary) operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312786/benefits-of-using-the-conditional-ternary-operator)

And this one, but it's concerning Java:

[Is there a PHP like short version of the ternary operator in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27387777/is-there-a-php-like-short-version-of-the-ternary-operator-in-java)

## What I have tried

Use the shorthand style of PHP (Failed due to syntax error)

```
string Value = "";
string Result = Value ?: "value was empty";
```

Use the shorthand style of JS (Failed because "*The `||` operator is not applicable to `string` and `string`.*")

```
string Value = "";
string Result = Value || "value was empty";
```

Comment: but the ternary operator is short hand. Is it really that difficult to type one line of code?

Comment: Your examples exploit the principle of truthy & falsey values, a concept that does not (by default) exist in strongly typed C#.

Comment: `value || "value was empty"` is not a short hand for a ternary operator. It's a logic statement. This isn't the same thing. Javascript just tends to coerce values because it's not strongly typed, unlike c#

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is no shorthand for when the string is empty. There is a shorthand for when the string is `null` :

```
string Value = null;
string Result = Value ?? "value was null";
```

Answer (score 6):

The coalesce `??` operator works only on `null`, but you could "customize" the behavior with an extension method:

```
public static class StringExtensions
{
    public static string Coalesce(this string value, string @default)
    {
        return string.IsNullOrEmpty(value)
            ? value
            : @default;
    }
}
```

and you use it like this:

```
var s = stringValue.Coalesce("value was empty or null");
```

But I don't think it is much better than the ternary.

Note: the `@` allows you to use reserved words as variable names.